# regex remove hash element from array items

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using `regex` to capture hashtags from a string like this:

```
var words = "#hashed words and some #more #hashed words";
var tagslistarr = words.match(/#\S+/g); 

console.log(tagslistarr);
```

this will return an array like this;

```
["#hashed", "#more", "#hashed"]
```

question: how can i remove the `#` hash sign from each of the array items?
this is what i would like in the end

```
["hashed", "more", "hashed"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var words = "#hashed words and some #more #hashed words";
var tagslistarr = words.match(/#\S+/g); 
tagslistarr = tagslistarr.map(function(x) { return x.substr(1); } );
console.log(tagslistarr)
```

prints

```
["hashed", "more", "hashed"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
words.match( /#\S+/g ).map( function(x) { return x.replace(/^#/,''); } );
```

A better way to do this would be zero-width assertions; unfortunately, JavaScript does not support look-behind assertions, only look-ahead.  (As an aside, here is a blog post about [mimicking lookbehind assertions in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).  I can't say as I care much for any of the solutions, but it's good reading nonetheless.  I sure hope lookbehind assertions make it into ES6.)

As pointed out by SimonR in the comments below, `Array.prototype.map` is not available in IE8 and below.  However, it's easy enough to polyfill:

```
if( !Array.prototype.map ) {
    Array.prototype.map = function(f) { 
        var r = []; 
        for( var i=0; i<this.length; i++ ) r[i] = f(this[i]); 
        return r; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, `array.map` is not supported in IE8 or less: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: True.  `Array.prototype.map` was introduced in JavaScript 1.6 in Nov 2005.  So it's more than seven years old.  If you (or your clients) are using a browser that isn't implementing seven year-old features, maybe it's time to switch, hmmm?  Also, it's easy enough to polyfill `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: In principal I completely agree with you, but unfortunately there are still a lot of folk out there in the real world using IE8 (or less!). Good point about the polyfill though, it's one reason I love javascript so much :)

Comment: I know...I'm getting increasingly frustrated with the "real world", though.  More and more, I'm taking the approach of just serving up a page that says "your browser is hopelessly out of date.  please upgrade" for people using ancient browsers.  There's a point at which you can't keep catering to people who won't upgrade....  Depends on the website/service you're offering, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use a capturing group in your regex:

```
words.replace(/#(\S+)/g, '$1');
```

**EDIT:**

To get them as an array:

```
var tagslistarr = words.match(/#\S+/g);

for( var i = 0, l = tagslistarr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  tagslistarr[ i ] = tagslistarr[ i ].substr( 1 );
}
```

Comment: That just removes the hashes without creating the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = "#hashed words and some #more #hashed words";
var regexp = /#(\S+)/g; // Capture the part of the match you want
var results = [];
var match;
while((match = regexp.exec(words))) // Loop through all matches
  results.push(match[1]);           // Add them to results array

console.log(results);
```